# How to put the result of mysql in a textbox?

Tags: php, pdo

I have an update page and a function for update, the updating is working my problem is that how can i put the value of an image in a text box?can somebody please help me?i'm using PDO..

**user.class.php**

```
public function upload($id,$FILE_NAME,$FILE_SIZE,$FILE_TYPE,$username,$password,$province)
{
$stmt = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE tish_images SET  FILE_NAME=:FILE_NAME,FILE_SIZE=:FILE_SIZE,FILE_TYPE=:FILE_TYPE,username=:username,password=:password,province=:province WHERE id=:id");

$errors= array();
foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $error )
{
    if ($error != UPLOAD_ERR_OK)
    {
        $errors[] = $_FILES['files']['name'][$key] . ' was not uploaded.';
        //continue;
        return FALSE;
    }
    $file_name = $key.$_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
    $file_size = $_FILES['files']['size'][$key];
    $file_tmp  = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
    $file_type = $_FILES['files']['type'][$key];  
    if($file_size > 2097152)
    {
        $errors[] = 'File size must be less than 2 MB';
        //continue;
        return FALSE;
    }

    try
    {
        $stmt->bindParam( ":id", $id);
        $stmt->bindParam( ":FILE_NAME", $file_name, PDO::PARAM_STR );
        $stmt->bindParam( ":FILE_SIZE", $file_size, PDO::PARAM_STR );
        $stmt->bindParam( ":FILE_TYPE", $file_type, PDO::PARAM_STR );
        $stmt->bindParam( ":username", $username);
        $stmt->bindParam( ":password", $password);
        $stmt->bindParam( ":province", $province);
        $stmt->execute();

        $desired_dir="image_uploads";

        if(is_dir($desired_dir)==false)
        {
            mkdir($desired_dir, 0700);// Create directory if it does not  exist
        }
        if(is_file($desired_dir.'/'.$file_name)==false)
        {
            move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,$desired_dir.'/'.$file_name);
            return TRUE;
        }
        else
        {    //rename the file if another one exist
            $new_file=$desired_dir.'/'.$file_name.time();
            move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,$new_file);  
            return TRUE;             
        }
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
      echo $e->getMessage();
      return FALSE;
    }   
}
}
```

**update.php**

```
<?php
include_once 'DB.php';
$username = isset($_POST['username']) ? $_POST['username'] : '';
$password = isset($_POST['password']) ? $_POST['password'] : '';
$province = isset($_POST['province']) ? $_POST['province'] : '';
$FILE_NAME = isset($_POST['FILE_NAME']) ? $_POST['FILE_NAME'] :$_POST['image_name']  ;
$FILE_SIZE = isset($_POST['FILE_SIZE']) ? $_POST['FILE_SIZE'] : '';
$FILE_TYPE = isset($_POST['FILE_TYPE']) ? $_POST['FILE_TYPE'] : '';



if(isset($_FILES['files'])){
$id = $_GET['id'];
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$province = $_POST['province'];

result = $crud->upload($id,$FILE_NAME,$FILE_SIZE,$FILE_TYPE,$username,$password,$province);
if (!$result['error'])
{
echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
echo 'document.getElementById("name").value="'.$data["FILE_NAME"].'"';
echo '</script>';
}
else{
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Updating Failed!'); </script>";
} 

}
if(isset($_GET['id']))
    {
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    extract($crud->getID($id));
    }
?>
```

**html**

```
<div id="Survey-Update">
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">
    <table class='table table-bordered'>
   <input type="file" name="files[]" id="name" value="" multiple/>
   <br />
   <br />
   <input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo $username; ?>">
   <br />
   <br />
   <input type="text" name="password" value="<?php echo $password ?>">
   <br />
   <br />
   <input type="text" name="province" value="<?php echo $province ?>">
   <input type="hidden" name="image_name" value="">
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of returning true, return an array like this

```
return ['error' =>false, 'file_name' => 'image file name']
```

change this

```
if($crud->upload($id,$FILE_NAME,$FILE_SIZE,$FILE_TYPE,$username,$password,$province))
{
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Successfully Updated!');
</script>";
}
else
{
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Updating Failed!'); </script>";
}
```

to

```
$result = $crud->upload($id,$FILE_NAME,$FILE_SIZE,$FILE_TYPE,$username,$password,$province);
if (!$result['error'])
{
  echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
  echo 'document.getElementById("name").value="'.$data["file_name"].'"';
  echo '</script>';
}
else{
   echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Updating Failed!'); </script>";
}
```

Comment: return ['error' =>false, 'file_name' => ''image file name']? where is this part?

Comment: after you completing the update and file move , replace `return true`

Comment: but what i want to happen is like this <input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo $username; ?>">

Comment: `<script type='text/javascript'>
   alert('Successfully Updated!');
   document.getElementByName('username').value( $result['file_name']  )
  </script>`

Comment: I tried your code but i get this error "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in D:\wamp\www\PDOS\upload_image\upload_update.php on line 22"

Comment: when i try to update theres no image now in the database

Comment: i already updated my code..i try to update a record with an image on it but when i hit the update it is successfully update but when see the database the image is gone..i don't change the image i just stay it as is

Comment: Oh, in that case you may want to add a hidden filed to your form and update it's value via js.        `<input type ="hidden"  name="image_name"  /> `  chaneg this line  like in your update.php     `$FILE_NAME = isset($_GET['FILE_NAME']) ? $_GET['FILE_NAME'] : '';` to     `$FILE_NAME = isset($_GET['FILE_NAME']) ? $_GET['FILE_NAME'] : '$_GET['image_name']';`. If you are not uploading an image during update, no need to pass $_FILES, it is empty.

Comment: ok, your update survery form uses post method but you are using `$_GET` to get values, I did change it `$_POST`. It's not secure when you have to send credentials

Comment: still not working..i want the image to be as is, but what happen is that when i try to edit the records without changing anything the image just dissapaer inside the database.